Patent owner now evaluating our technology that was subject to an infringement lawsuit
Several years ago, our firm was accused of using a technology that our competitor claimed infringed on their patents.
We went to mediation and agreed to destroy all infringing technologies in our possession and to not make/use them in the future until the patents expired. The exception: a client of ours was permitted to retain the technology we had given them as part of a contract we had performed.
Now, it appears that our competitor has somehow acquired that device from our former client and is performing test on it to see how it compares to their technology.
We did have a right of first refusal to buy back that technology from our client, in which case we would have purchased it back and destroyed according to the terms of the mediation settlement.
Our competitors existing patents expire in September of 2025....so, we are concerned that they will now seek new patents using our "infringing" technology.
We know there is a contractual issue with our former client and the right to first refusal- our question is, are there any USPTO issue here? Candor, prior art, ethics violations?
Thank you,
Matt

Only a small portion of your scenario is on topic here. If you worded it less specifically and made it a hypothetical, a question might be drafted that is appropriate for Law SE.
The thing your company made several years ago could have both infringing and patent worthy. Often an improved system infringes a patent but also has some novel and non-obvious aspect that can be patentable. The catch is that having a patent does not provide any right to make the invention. You would need a license from the first patent owner. Without your permission they couldn’t make it either.
It might have been possible to license your improvement to your competitor as part of your settlement with them years ago, but is moot now.
Unless your client kept the device away from public disclosure and use its  existence might constitute prior that bars any future patent by anyone.
Patents filed in the U.S. require declarations signed by the true inventors stating they are true inventors. Hopefully your competitor would not knowingly file a fraudulent application.

Thank you George.
